# Simple math iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm pretty new to programming, and I just need to be pointed in the right direction with this.

I'm trying to make an iOS app in Xcode (using Objective-c) that takes in the user's input and uses a 3x3 cramer's rule matrix to feed back a coordinate. I've been learning about properties and methods, and I'm just confused as to how I can get the user's input (12 numbers), alter them mathematically, and print out the answer.

So far, I've been able to, using a textfield, a label, and a button, take the user's input and feed it out through the label. But I understand, from previous questions, that properties are like the addresses of certain objects, not the actual objects.

It would be awesome if someone could just show me how to take the user input from one textfield and multiply by the user input from another textfield, just so I can see how to do this.

Here are both files:

```
//  ViewController.h
//  Cramer

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

// Objects are given addresses:


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *box_a;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *box_b;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *hiLabel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *clickButton;

@end
```

AND

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  Cramer

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// When button is clicked, user input from textfield is fed out through label:

- (IBAction)clickButton:(id)sender {

    NSInteger number1 = [self.box_a.text integerValue];
    NSInteger number2 = [self.box_b.text integerValue];

    NSInteger prod = number1 * number2;

    self.hiLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%@", @(prod)];

}

@end
```

Both errors are on      self.hiLabel line

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
NSInteger number1 = [self.textField1.text integerValue];
NSInteger number2 = [self.textField2.text integerValue];

NSInteger prod = number1 * number2;
```

To set prod value in UILabel or UITextField:

```
self.textField1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @(prod)];
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have an issue: Where does it print the answer to? I put in my object's names for label1 and label2 and tried putting in my label's name for prod and nothing happened.

Comment: To put an answer you can do something like this: self.label3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%@", @(prod)];

Comment: `[self.textField1.text integerValue]` might communicate the idea better, as it's being fed in from a pair of `UITextField`s...`

Comment: Ok. Sorry for the illiteracy, but where exactly would I put that? And I'm assuming I would put in my output label's name in for label3?

Comment: @user3587655, you can insert this code somewhere where button action takes place. The result you can use anywhere: UILabel, UITextField ets. Just convert NSInteger to NSString like this: NSString *numberAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%@", prod];

Comment: I'm getting 4 different errors: One says that an "incompatible pointer types sending 'char[3]' to parameter of type 'NSString', and another is saying how there is an implicit conversion of a non-Objective-C pointer

Comment: @user3587655, I have updated my answer. Made a mistake in stringWithFormat:

Comment: Ok, if you look back in my question I put in what my code currently is. I'm getting two errors and the build failed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First one is: implicit conversion of a non-Objective-C pointer type 'char*' to 'NSString' is disallowed with ARC and second one is: incompatible pointer types ending 'char [3]'to parameter of type 'NSString*'

Comment: @user3587655, this error is something from your code, not from my sample. Please, provide full code and see line on which compiler finds that error.

Comment: Both errors are on this line:  self.hiLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%@", @(prod)];

Comment: @user3587655, ok. What types are box_a, box_b, hiLabel? Please, update your question with interface and implementation files.

Comment: @user3587655, doh... change to [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @(prod)]; forgot to put "@" char before "" string.

Comment: Alright, so that took care of both errors. But now the simulator says "build succeeded", but the simulator is black. This is what it says: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ViewController 0x8aa9660> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key outputlabel.'